# Black screen of death after trying a previous restore. I can only open bios. WRE-no load

Tags: windows-10, boot, restore, black-screen-of-death

I have tried for 3 days of all and every possible way to fix.

I am getting the black screen of death after trying a previous restore. I can only open bios. WRE-not loading.

Tried USB boot, nothing.

How do I fix anything to even just get to WRE, CMD, MSconfig, wipe HDD, restart fresh?

Comment: Try to Reset the BIOS to default values. I hope that your disk isn't Bitlocked (or that you have the recovery key on some external media).

Comment: It’s not bitlock. I have reset bios. I’ve tried Boot order, with different USB, as well as different versions. Once in a while I will get windows logo and auto repair, but always continues to black screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't boot from a Windows installation media, then either the
installation media is bad, or it doesn't conform to the BIOS settings
(Legacy/EFI).

The other possibility is that you had a very serious hardware crash
and should consult a repair-shop. We can't help if this is indeed the case.

Comment: If the case my HD crashed, I should still be able to use USB as first boot to enter windows? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right - a hardware crash could be related to the motherboard. Most such crashes are caused by electricity, so I hope that the computer is protected by a surge-protector or a UPS.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).